# Split branch into one branch per commit

Tags: git, github, branch, pull-request

In this project I'm working on, I'm supposed to commit my progress to a repo using pull requests, and every commit has to be in a different branch. The problem is that the last 3 commits were pushed in a single pull requests and I'm supposed to move them into separate branches each. I tried reverting and creating new branches but it got messed up and I'm back at square 1.

Comment: Wait...do you mean each commit has to be sitting on top of the same base in separate branches, or do you need three branche will successive commits?

Comment: what are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: just explain step by step what did you do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer, I will assume that your branch is called `feature`, and that `feature` has the three commits in question as its three most recent commits.

Create a new branch from `feature`:

```
git checkout -b onecommit
```

Nuke the two most recent commits, leaving the first of three commits remaining:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~2
```

Now push this branch containing just the first commit to your repo:

```
git push origin onecommit
```

To obtain a branch with just two commits you would follow a similar process:

```
git checkout -b twocommits
git reset --hard HEAD~1
git push origin twocommits
```